# Rails 3 Devise Ajax error messages

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So Im using this app, [devise ajax login](https://github.com/jni-/Rails3-devise-ajax-login), to do ajax login.

Right now when the user logs in it is handled by the sessions controller which returns either a 401 or returns a success

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
 sign_in(resource_name, resource)
 return render :json => {:success => true, :content => render_to_string(:layout =>  false, :partial => 'sessions/manager')}
end

def failure
  return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
 end
end
```

Is there a way to use ajax to insert flash/devise error messages for why the user failed login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get your question. Could you clarify it a little bit? It's just that you are already dealing well with the success/failure of your login and returning a message accordingly.

Was it something like this you were looking for?

```
return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => [t("devise.failure.invalid")]}
```